# Flex: Printed data grid makes huge files

Tags: apache-flex, printing, datagrid

I've an AIR app which prints a couple of DataGrids with approximately 3 pages worth of data each. I get great-looking printouts, but the printing is slow - I noticed that printing these 6 pages + a title page and a page of lightweight images was sent to the printer in a file of almost 50 MB (on Windows). Is this a normal size for a printed DataGrid? Is there anything I can do to make it smaller and faster?

Related: [Printing from AIR/Flex application causes large files being sent to printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015289/printing-from-air-flex-application-causes-large-files-being-sent-to-printer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its basically sending an image to the printer, hence it being great looking but huge.

A totally unscientific experiment messing around with Photoshop, I managed to hit 100 Megs for 3 sides of A4 pretty easily.

Other than messing around with stage quality setting, or experimenting with printing as bitmap / vector... There aren't many options!

Take away message, printing in Flash / AIR isn't good enough yet... but Adobe are aware of that.

Comment: Thanks. It'll have to stay gorgeous but huge for a while then, and hopefully it'll get better at a later date. I'd better whip up something nice to show while it's printing though...=)